# android - Facebook Login, Error while executing "ProxyAuthAppLoginQuery"

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate Facebook Authentication in my Android app, but it is throwing This `Server Error 1675030` with `error executing "ProxyAuthAppLoginQuery"`.

I have double checked everything and everything seems in place. The authentication does succeed if there is no facebook app installed but fails while authenticating with Facebook app installed.

Some Information regarding stuff:

```
Facebook SDK : 4.22.1
Facebook API : v2.9
Android Compile and Target SDK version : 25
Android Build Tools : 25.0.3
```

Other than that I have also set app available to public so there may be no permission restriction even while testing

Answer (score 0):

So after trying many different combination and fixes it turned out there was nothing wrong with api, sdk or anything.

Basically I was a Beta tester for facebook app and had its beta version installed, leaving the beta tester position uninstalling and installing the stable version of facebook worked for me

Hope it helps someone out there..